# Converting an array with values in log scale to a regular array

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

I am trying to plot a histogram of elements of a downloaded .py file. The array had a shape (200, 3649, 13). So I had reshaped it to a 2D array by preforming the function

```
samples = chain[:,-2000:,:].reshape((-1,13))
```

I hence plotted the histogram by doing

```
plt.hist(samples[:,3])
```

The graph gave me values in log scale, but I need to plot it in a linear scale. How do I proceed?

Comment: What base is the log?

Comment: log to the base 10

Comment: `samps = 10**(samples[:,3])` will do 10^x for each element x in samples[:,3]

Comment: Or if you don't want to scale the samples, you can scale the plot by doing `plt.xscale('linear')`